# Snowflake - split a string based on number/letters

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

For column A, the example values are

```
SRAB-123456-CRTCA-700042125
TRAB-B03456-CBAC-12342125
```

I want to split these values so they will become

```
SRAB-123456
CRTCA-700042125
TRAB-B03456
CBAC-12342125
```

The pattern is tricky: the length of each part (SRAB, 123456, CRTCA, etc.) is random.
Only one pattern is fixed: left part (SRAB,CRTCA,TRAB,CBAC,etc.) is a string only contains letters. But the right part could be letters/number.

Comment: Is the separator fixed (each pattern separated by '-') or that is also not fixed?

Comment: @Pankaj Actually the separator could be - or _ , I was using split_to_table for those values using _ as separator, but its not working for - since value also contains -

Comment: Do you always have exactly two pairs of values? Could you have `SRAB-123456-CRTCA-700042125-GFRT-9657584847`?

Comment: @PhilCoulson not always two pairs - this is random too lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be done with [SPLIT_TO_TABLE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/split_to_table.html)(the number of sections could vary):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE tab
AS
SELECT 1 AS id, 'SRAB-123456-CRTCA-700042125' col
UNION 
SELECT 2 AS id, 'TRAB-B03456_CBAC-12342125';
```

Query:

> *Actually the separator could be - or _*

```
SELECT *
FROM tab
,LATERAL split_to_table(REPLACE(tab.col, '_', '-'), '-') s ;
```

Output:

[image]

EDIT:

```
SELECT tab.id, tab.col, LISTAGG(s.VALUE, '-') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY s.index)
FROM tab
,LATERAL split_to_table(REPLACE(tab.col, '_', '-'), '-') s 
GROUP BY tab.id, tab.col, SEQ, CEIL(INDEX/2);
```

Output:

[image]

EDIT 2:

> *the table doesnt have ID column to show the order of each row,*

The code still works!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE tab
AS
SELECT  'SRAB-123456-CRTCA-700042125' col
UNION 
SELECT 'TRAB-B03456_CBAC-12342125';


SELECT  tab.col, LISTAGG(s.VALUE, '-') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY s.index) AS result
FROM tab
,LATERAL split_to_table(REPLACE(tab.col, '_', '-'), '-') s 
GROUP BY  tab.col, SEQ, CEIL(INDEX/2);
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: thanks but the values I want are 'SRAB-123456', 'CRTCA-700042125',...

Comment: @Hannah That is also easy to achieve. See edit

Comment: thanks! the table doesnt have ID column to show the order of each row, I'm trying to put row number by using row_number() over (order by) - is there another way to add the sequence number into each row?

Comment: @Hannah You should fix your table design and get a proper primary key column in there.

Comment: @Hannah The ID column DOES NOT HAVE to exist(though is recommended). The code works without it.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda thanks for the help - im not allowed to modify ddl so I ended up use row_number to manually add row id.

Answer (score 1):

We could use `SPLIT_PART` here:

```sql
SELECT val
FROM
( 
    SELECT id, SPLIT_PART(a, '-', 1) || '-' || SPLIT_PART(a, '-', 2) AS val, 1 AS ord
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, SPLIT_PART(a, '-', 3) || '-' || SPLIT_PART(a, '-', 4), 2
) t
ORDER BY id, ord;
```

I assume here that there exist some column `id` which is providing the ordering in your sample data as shown.  If not, then it may not be possible to generate the output you want in that order.